# Wrong MinGW enviroment detected by Clion

Tags: clion, mingw-w64

For the past few hours I've tried to update MinGW. I had an old 5.0 version and I wanted to install SFML but it requires 7.3.0
Clion sees for whatever reason MinGW version 6.0

[image]

But i have updated to 7.3.0 with the download link provided by SFML

[image]

[image]

and no, I did not forget to change the environment path

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Please keep it easy with the hate, I am a beginner.

Comment: Use mingw-w64 package in msys2. link: http://www.msys2.org/. It updates gcc with ported pacman.

Comment: installed it, used pacman -Syu and pacman -Su as it said on the page, do I need to do anything else? if not, it did not work

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634

Comment: I kind of made it work but not really, it only updated to 7.0, I need specific 7.3 for w/e reason. I can't find anywhere how to do it. It was also missing GDB with msys2 but I think I fixed it. That aside the 7.0 is still a problem, any idea?

Comment: if I do the gcc --version in cmd it shows me the right one, the problem is that clion shows me another mingw environment version than the one I have installed for whatever reason, it does not recognize the right one, in cmd it appears 7.3.0 build by msys2 but clion says it's just 7.0 =\